# Cannot create lambda function on AWS with Administrator permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a simple lambda function using Hello World example.
No matter what I try, I always get "Request failed with status code 403".
My account has AdministratorAccess.
I tried policy simulator and it says I do have permission to create a function.

[the screenshot of the error from AWS Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1coy.png)

Comment: You are not the first one reporting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764286/aws-lambda-create-function-request-failed-with-status-code-403?noredirect=1#comment114511019_64764286). What region are you using?

Comment: I am using Tokyo (ap-northeast-1) but also tried us-east-1. Same error.

Comment: Can you go to "personal Health dashobord"? Maybe an issue is limited to your selected accounts only. I checked in us-east-1 and I have no problems creating functions.

Comment: Thanks, I went there and didn't find anything on the dashboard. However, in Event Logs, I found the "Risk IAM quarantine" event which is in open status... I went to support console and found that there has been some emails going on and basically they're saying there was a suspicious activity and therefore limiting my access... this could be it. I am in the middle of resolving the case and will let you know how it goes! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Checking out `Event Logs` in [AWS Personal Health Dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/technology/personal-health-dashboard/) shows that the permissions on the account could be temporary limited due to `Risk IAM quarantine` and some suspicious activity.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In their email, they basically asked me to "delete (rotate)  API keys for all IAM users as these might be potentially compromised". I followed the instruction and invalidated all API keys from all IAM users, and replied to the support. After a while, I just went ahead and retried creating a HelloWorld lambda. Guess what, it all works now!  Thank you very much again

Comment: hi @YuSasaki , I was facing the same issue. Though I made changes based on your comment and now its started working properly. Thanks again.