# AWS Root user cannot create lambda function via console or aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, permissions

I imagine there would be a lot of unpack here, my root user is part of the organization in which it should be granted all privileges. However, when I attempt to create any lambda function via cloud formation or lambda function console. I get a 403, with a null message.

There's no troubleshooting docs that I was able to find and this problem has eaten about a weeks worth of my hobby-dev time. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Such error is often given when your account has been compromized, or at least AWS thinks it was. So they detected possible security breach and limited its permissions, including root permissions. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64778412/cannot-create-lambda-function-on-aws-with-administrator-permission?noredirect=1#comment114534289_64778412) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764286/aws-lambda-create-function-request-failed-with-status-code-403/65213533#65213533) for similar cases.

Comment: Perhaps it is because I'm outside of the free-tier now? The personal health dashboard didn't have any feedback for me.

Comment: The AWS Free Tier is a billing discount. It has zero impact on your ability to _use_ AWS services.

Comment: Please Edit your Question to provide more information so that we can attempt to reproduce your situation. For example, where/how did this 403 error appear? What were you doing? What was the exact error message? Thank you.