# Cannot Create a Lambda Function on AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I cannot create a Lambda function. After clicking the create function button, the loading icon appears for around 10 sec then disappear. No error message display. No function is created. It's been an issue for me couple of days now.
[image: no error message appears]

I also inspected the network tab and found several 403 code responses with this error message

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

[image: 403 error responses]

I've tried these without success

- Use different browsers eg. Edge, Chrome, Firefox
- Try on another machine
- Sync my machine time

Info

- The AWS account is root account
- No issue on personal health dashboard
- Creating a function using cli works
- I just notice that I also can't create a new layer, layer version.
- Editing source code of existing functions via console editor does not work as well. When clicking deploy button, a strange error message "[object Object]" appear, and also get the 403 signature not match in the network tab.

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried creating a function using cli?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66721029/aws-root-user-cannot-create-lambda-function-via-console-or-aws-sdk) seems to be the same problem but not solved. BTW, you should create an IAM user instead of using root account.

Comment: Is it totally new account?

Comment: Creating a function using cli works.

Comment: No, not a new account. I've been using lambda on this account for over 5 year now.  Never had an issue.

Comment: Same here. I created an IAM user and tried again, but with the same results: 403 InvalidSignatureException when the console tried to do a POST call to https://lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions Previously I never had problems like this.

Comment: I filed a support request and they fixed the bug. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a support request and they told me it was a bug in their system. They fixed it and now it works.

Comment: Facing similar issue. Lambda functions are not displayed and cant create new functions either. Create function keeps loading and stops. Have raised a support request.