# new 403 error when deploying lambda function, how do I fix this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am attempting to deploy my lambda function from github.

Since this last worked, I have not changed credentials or anything like that. I have not even logged into AWS. But I am getting a 403 error when I attempt to deploy my lambda function. Why might this be occurring?

[image]

I can't even edit and save from within the AWS console, it gives me a 403. Why is AWS giving itself a 403?

[image]

Here's my PHD:

[image]

I also can't even upload a zip through the aws console:

[image]

I can't create a new lambda function either, I get an unexplained 403 error. I am 100% locked out of everything lambda.

Comment: The error suggest that some permissions have changed.

Comment: I haven't changed any permissions. I'm even getting a 403 error from inside of the AWS root console, how could the root console not have access to a lambda function it owns?

Comment: Is your account part of AWS Organization? If yes, at the AWS Org level it could be denied. If not, you can go to CloudTrial Events history, and look for any events related to your function or permissions around that time you think something has changed. Also you can check personal health dashboard, to check if there are any aws issues which could be related to lambda or iam.

Comment: It is not in an organization.

Comment: So check CloudTrial or health dashboard. Also if you work with teammates, maybe someone else did change something?

Comment: Oh, and check for security issues in PhD (personal health). Sometimes aws can block some actions in your account if it thinks it has been compromised or was doing something strange.

Comment: I've made new security keys and it's still not working. I don't have any teammates.

Personal health doesn't appear to me to be having any problems. It's basically empty.

I don't understand what could possibly have changed such that I can't edit something from within the AWS console itself.

At this point I think I need to just make a new account and set it up from scratch again.

Comment: There are no any events in PhD (Event log)?

Comment: I have posted the events in the event log. The security notice is an irrelevant notice. Everything else seems totally benign.

Comment: I see. Just to double check, there were no emails from aws about any security issue. If not, then for now I don't have more ideas what could it be. Sorry.

Comment: Nope, no emails from AWS.

Comment: Ok, so after some thought, I recovered my password earlier today. Could that be responsible for the issue?

Comment: Your issue is consistent with some security incident and AWS limiting your account. Maybe they though the password change was unauthorized? You can contact AWS support to check with them.

Comment: AWS technical support requires a paid plan to use unfortunately.

Comment: Check other similar question such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059561/cant-create-delete-publish-lambda-on-amazon-aws-getting-403-access-denied/65118711). Maybe you can find some hints there how

Comment: No problem. If you figure it out, please let me know. I'm curious to know what was the cause of the issue.

Comment: It's possible that AWS logged you out but your browser is giving the appearance that you are still logged in. If you click on other AWS services, do they load properly?